# How to add Toggle Inline Help button to config

Tags: joomla-4.x, component-configuration

Since J4.1 help text (description) is hidden in the config.xml file for my component.  So how do I add the "Toggle Inline Help" button to my config view of my component?
I can add this toggle button in my admin edit form easily enough using

```
ToolbarHelper::inlinehelp('hide-aware-inline-help');
```

But I need this in the configuration options view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.  In the config.xml file add an element such as:

```
<inlinehelp button="show" />
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Glen, don't forget to accept your own answer.